# Borel Measures: Density

Tags: integration, measure-theory

*This is a build-up for: [Jacobian](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1013595/79762)*

Given a sigma-finite measure.

Consider a finite measure:
$$\kappa:\Sigma(\Omega)\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}_+:\quad\kappa(\Omega)<\infty$$

By Lebesgue decomposition:
$$\kappa\ll\lambda\iff\kappa\int\rho\mathrm{d}\lambda\quad(\rho\geq0)$$

So for integrability one has:
$$f\in\mathcal{L}(\kappa)\iff f\rho\in\mathcal{L}(\lambda)$$

And the integral computes as:
$$f\in\mathcal{L}(\kappa):\quad\int f\mathrm{d}\kappa=\int f\rho\mathrm{d}\lambda$$

How to prove these relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By monotone convergence one has:
$$h\geq0:\quad\int h\mathrm{d}\kappa=\lim\int s_n\mathrm{d}\kappa=\lim\int s_n \rho\mathrm{d}\lambda=\int h\rho\mathrm{d}\lambda\quad(s_n\uparrow h)$$

By dominated convergence one has:
$$f\in\mathcal{L}(\kappa):\quad\int f\mathrm{d}\kappa=\lim\int s_n\mathrm{d}\kappa=\lim\int s_n\rho\mathrm{d}\lambda=\int f\rho\mathrm{d}\lambda\quad(|s_n|\leq|f|)$$