# Complex Measures: Jacobian

Tags: integration, measure-theory

*This is a follow-up to: [Densities](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1013557/79762)*

Given a complex measure.

Consider another complex measure:
$$\nu:\Sigma(\Omega)\to\mathbb{C}$$

Criterion for Jacobians:
$$|\nu|\ll|\mu|\iff\nu\int J\mathrm{d}\mu\quad(J\in\mathcal{L}(\mu))$$

So for integrability one has:
$$f\in\mathcal{L}(\mu)\iff fJ\in\mathcal{L}(\nu)$$
And the integral computes as:
$$f\in\mathcal{L}(\mu):\quad\int f\mathrm{d}\nu=\int fJ\mathrm{d}\mu$$

How to prove these relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex measures one has:
$$\mu=\int u\mathrm{d}|\mu|\quad(|u|=1)$$
$$\nu=\int v\mathrm{d}|\nu|\quad(|v|=1)$$
and for their integral by definition:
$$f\in\mathcal{L}(\mu):=\mathcal{L}(|\mu|):\quad\int f\mathrm{d}\mu:=\int fu\mathrm{d}|\mu|$$
$$f\in\mathcal{L}(\nu):=\mathcal{L}(|\nu|):\quad\int f\mathrm{d}\nu:=\int fv\mathrm{d}|\mu|$$

This gives a quick check without words:
$$|\nu|\ll|\mu|\implies|\nu|=\int h\mathrm{d}|\mu|\implies\nu=\int \frac{v}{u}h\mathrm{d}\mu$$
$$\nu=\int J\mathrm{d}\mu\implies|\nu|=\int\frac{u}{v}J\mathrm{d}|\mu|\implies|\nu|\ll|\mu|$$

The remaining follows from the results on positive measures.